# Zephyr OS: multiple GPIOs init using DTS phandle array

Tags: zephyr-rtos

On my board I have 10 LEDs connected to different GPIOs.
In board's DTS file all pins defined as

```
leds {
    compatible = "gpio-leds";
    led0: led_0 {
        gpios = <&gpio0 28 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
        label = "Green LED 0";
    };
...
    led9: led_9 {
        gpios = <&gpio0 29 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
        label = "Green LED 9";
    };
};
```

and in code I have a long sequence of device_get_binding/gpio_pin_configure

How I can use UTIL_LISTIFY and how to correctly describe pin array in DTS file to control LEDs using indexes? In general, I'd like to have a solution similar to cx1276.c driver, but in user space.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if nobody else answers, I'll post my solution.
The best way to handle HW operations in Zephyr - writing device driver.
In my case, I put all pin definitions into a separate DTS file and organize the whole LED work as a single syscall function. It can show either pre-defined patterns or generated on-the-fly.

Github Gist with solution:

https://gist.github.com/Delsian/f64e7a26ebc67c3b9ea4cf04d057f15c

Comment: I have been struggling to find help on how to use zephyr even for the simplest of tasks like toggling a GPIO. I dont know if i am up to the task of writing my own dts file for HW yet, but how can i simply add a node on the baord dts file , the node will just be a pin or array of pins which I can toggle using the api functions.  I am not using leds  , so this  "gpio-leds" would be a misnomer for my purposes, im thinking the propery way would be to use compatible = "st,stm32-gpio "  in my case  but I am unsure how to fill out the properties and then toggle the pin.